# How to view the exported functions of a smart contract in MultiversX

Tags: smartcontracts, multiversx

Is there any way to see the exported functions of a smart contract deployed by somebody else given the address of the contract?
I tried in explorer and all I was able to see was the compiled code.

Comment: I think the only way to list the endpoints without the source code is to have the abi.json.

Otherwise you can also execute the transaction you want via a dapp (like maiar exchange) and see what is sent in the explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to have access to the contract's `.abi.json` file.

If you don't have it, then the "reverse engineer" way would be to take the contract's bytecode from the explorer and open it with a web assembly interpreter (e.g. the WebAssembly VSCode extension).

Thus you'll be able to see the contract's interpreted web assembly functions and their opcodes. You should be able to find a list of entries like `export "function_name" (func $rust_function_name)`.

From this point on, you'll either have to employ some educated guesses to figure out endpoints from views along with their corresponding parameters... or try them out exhaustively.